# RxJava error handling for hot observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I'm pretty new to RxJava and have some questions on patterns etc. 
I'm creating an observable using the code below:

```
    public Observable<Volume> getVolumeObservable(Epic epic) {
        return Observable.create(event -> {
            try {
                listeners.add(streamingAPI.subscribeForChartCandles(epic.getName(), MINUTE, new HandyTableListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdate(int i, String s, UpdateInfo updateInfo) {
                        if (updateInfo.getNewValue(CONS_END).equals(ONE)) {
                            event.onNext(new Volume(Integer.parseInt(updateInfo.getNewValue(LAST_TRADED_VOLUME))));
                        }
                    }
                }));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Error from volume observable", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Everything is working as expected, but I have some questions on error handling. 
If I understand correctly, this is to be viewed as a "hot observble", i.e. events will happen regardless of there being a subscription or not (onUpdate is a callback used by a remote server which I have no control over).

I've chosen not to call onError here since I don't want the observable to stop emitting events in case of a single exception. Is there a better pattern to be used? .retry() comes to mind, but I'm not sure that it makes sense for a hot observable?

Also, how is the observable represented when the subscriptions is created, but before the first onNext is called? Is it just an Observable.empty()

Comment: Where do you expect errors to come from? From `listeners.add()` or from `onUpdate()`? Can you give an example of error condition that you want subscribers to be notified of.

Comment: I guess you a little bit misunderstanding hot/cold Observable . This is not hot, every subscriber has their own listener to emit events. And even you didn't unregister your listener in dispose. The observable won't emit event after your dispose because of the Observable.create mechanism.

Comment: Could be both listeners.add() and onUpdate(). Unfortunately the API I'm using is very poorly specified.

Comment: Thanks, I realize now that my producer has to be created outside the Observable.create() for it to be considered hot

Answer (score 2):

1) Your observable is not *hot*. The distinguishing factor is whether multiple subscribers share the same subscription. `Observable.create()` invokes subscribe function for every subscriber, i.e. it is *cold*.

It is easy to make it *hot* though. Just add `share()` operator. It will subscribe with first subscriber and unsubscribe with last one. Do not forget to implement *unsubscribe* functionality with something like this:

```
event.setCancellable(() -> listeners.remove(...));
```

2) Errors could be *recoverable* and *not recoverable*.

In case you consider an error to be self-recoverable (no action required from your side) you should not call `onError` as this will kill your observable (no further events would be emitted). You can possibly notify your subscribers by emitting special `Volume` message with error details attached.

In case an error is fatal, e.g. you have failed to add listener, so there could be no further messages, you should not silently ignore this. Emit `onError` as your observable is not functional anyway.

In case an error requires actions from you, typically retry, or retry with timeout, you can add one of `retryXxx()` operators. Do this after `create()` but *before* `share()`.

3) `Observable` is an object with `subscribe()` method. How exactly it is represented depends on the method you created it with. See source code of `create()` for example.